# Cutting and Pasting Cells in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The Function of the program is to find the first row that has an empty cell, next to that cell is a number that needs to be cut and pasted in the previous row on column 26.

-I am trying to run a loop that goes through the entire sheet and deletes the row once copied and pasted.

-If there is already data inside it will skip it and continue on.

-The Second Method is my most promising but I just can't seem to find out how to run the format of Cells(x,1)

(Method One)

```
Dim x As Integer
x = 1
this = x - 1
rowdelete = x

If Cells(x, 1) = "" Then
Cells(x, 1).Select.Cut
Cells(x - 1, 26).PasteSpecial
Rows([rowdelete]).EntireRow.Delete

End If
```

(Method Two)

```
Dim x As Integer
x = 1
this = x - 1
rowdelete = x

If Cells(x, 1) = "" Then
Cells(x, 1).Select.Cut
Cells(x - 1, 26).PasteSpecial
Rows([rowdelete]).EntireRow.Delete

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i'm just missing something but your Method1 and Method2 look identical to me. I think your issue was that you were trying to paste to `Row 0` which doesn't exist. It's also good practice to define all your `ranges` and `cells` or excel will take whatever is active at the time.

Try the below code that loops through blank cells in Col A and doesn't use the Clipboard which should make things much faster for you.

```
Sub LoopThroughBlanks()

    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim Cell As Range

    Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Be sure to change this to your worksheet name!

    With ws
        'Find last row of data in worksheet
        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row
        'Loop through blank cells in col a
        For Each Cell In .Range("A1:A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            If Cell.Row = 1 Then
                .Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
            End If
            'Copy to column 26
            Cell.Offset(-1, 25).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .Rows(Cell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
        Next Cell
    End With
End Sub
```